NextJs SSR - How to pass request data from an SSR page fetch to backend api call?
I have a fetch call coded as per the nextJs docs
In SSR - I am unable to get user data in the Page.jsx as req.user is not available in this context. In previous versions there was ctx got getServerSideProps. Is there anything like that in NextJS 14 where I can make req.user available in an SSR page?
Client/Browser -  if I simply use the URL in the browser http://localhost:3000/api/user, I get the data.
Page.jsx - SSR based file placed in APP Router
async function getUser() {
  // I have also tried with 'use client' here
  let user;
  await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/user`).then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {console.log(data); user=data;});
  return user;
}

And in my api, I need req.user as that is how I can extract some fields of the user data
api/user.js
handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) return res.json({ user: "req is empty so can't get user" }); 
  return res.json({ user: extractUser(req) });
});

Server side terminal console logs:

Localhost api url in browser:


What is req.user? How is it populated? I suspect some middleware that uses cookies but would be nice to know (and get the code).
